# SQL text search with wildcards

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to do a text search on 2 fields of my full-InnoDB MySql database.
In the past i used:

```
Field1 LIKE %text% OR Field2 LIKE %text%
```

But now my data increased a lot and "Like" searching became too slow.
So I started to search for another, better solution.

Since now I tried:

- Fulltext indices (MATCH(...) AGAINST) -> Doesn't support leading wildcards
- CONTAINS -> not avaiable in MySql (only Transact-Sql)
- Reverse fulltext indices -> work with leading wildcards but not if the match is in the middle
- REGEXP -> not really faster than LIKE

I used MyISAM "Shadow tables" for the Fulltext indices...

I don't want to use external search engines like Sphinx, Lucene or s.e

So my question:
Is there something I forgot? 
I am thinking of a trick to get bothwildcards work. Like an CONTEXT Index in Oracle. 
Or I don't know...that's why I ask ;)

Comment: there's no too much to do with `like`. it has to search word by word, if you already create the index, try improving the hardware, BTW can you show us the command `explain`

Comment: Safe for storing words in your shadow tables like `'alongword longword ongword ngword gword word ord'`, if you need leading wildcards... LIKE is the only solution, and slow. Either the need for the leading wildcard, or the dislike for other search engines needs to go if you want to do this with any kind of performance unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The leading percent '%' sign in your pattern is causing a table scan to be performed, hence the performance degradation as your data volumeincreased.

Note that this also reflects that yor data is no longe "relational" due to the non-atomic nature of he fields; that your DB is hene no longer a Relational DataBase, not withstanding that you are still using a RDBMS as the data storage engine.

The true solution is to restructure the data table by converting Field1 and Field2 back to a set of relational, meaning atomic, fields. This may be beyond any reasonable scope for the project at hand, I know; but it is the solution.